# Nested link documents not loadable when running in Design Automation (Forge)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am writing a Revit (2023) addin in C# to export geometry using CustomExporter.  When I run in Revit on my desktop, nested link documents are automatically loaded and I am able to traverse and export their geometry.  When I run in Design Automation, uploading links and nested links using nested rvtFile references per https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step7-post-workitem/, nested link documents are not automatically loaded, and attempting to explicitly load them using RevitLinkType.Load() results in a "Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.InvalidOperationException: This RevitLinkType is not a top-level link." error.  All links are attachments with relative paths.

I can see that the uploaded documents are successfully saved to the input folder on the Design Automation VM (with a path like T:\Aces\Jobs<random ID>) with the correct file names, and my code is successfully able to load the root document and access the top-level links (whose documents are loaded automatically), but I can't figure out how to access the content of the nested links.  What do I need to do to be able to traverse the full hierarchy?

Comment: Are you RVT file Cloud Model, or just local RVT files? If just local files, have you tried to pack them in the ZIP as the input? Revit DA should unzip it and load the links automatically with my experience.

Comment: This seems to happen with cloud models which have been downloaded and saved "as a central model in its current location" (I'm not entirely clear on what that means).  All linked files are included in the input ZIP.  It doesn't happen with cloud models which haven't been opened/saved locally, or local files which have haven't been published to cloud.  I assume something in the process of converting from a cloud model to a "central" model is breaking the links.

Comment: You don't need to specify the link references if the cloud model has been downloaded locally and packed into ZIP. Just leave it as it should be. DA will handle the link things itself. All you need is to specify the ZIP in the workitme as the input and specify the host model by the `pathInZip` field.